# Emberjs update template with localstorage

Tags: ember.js, local-storage, session-storage

I would like to know if it was possible to retrieve the data from the localstorage/sessionStorage and display them in a template ?

I save my data like this :

```
localstorage["user.name"] = "username";
localstorage["user.email"] = "email";
[...]
```

And I do the same way for the sessionStorage. But I would like to use it to display those information in one of my template. And that would be update without being refresh.

For exemple, I have a table, and this table might have some data or row removed or add.

I found this adapter https://github.com/rpflorence/ember-localstorage-adapter but I'm not using ember-Data.

Should I use it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ember-localstorage-adapter works with Ember-Data. It writes and reads from local storage automatically. If you use that, you just need to create a DS.Model and set adapter for the store, you don't need to set values manually. If you do not prefer to use the adapter, you can load the data yourself in the model hook of the route.

Comment: I would rather not use the Adapter if its possible. So I might do it directly from the model hook, but can I just do this : `return localstorage["user"];` to load the data ?

Other question, do you think its a good idea as well to use JQuery to update the data directly in the template instead of loading it from the model ?

Comment: Yes you can use localstorage directly but ember-localstorage-adapter makes it very easy and smooth. I would recommend that. If you are using ember do not need to use jQuery directly. Ember will remove jquery dependency in near future.